# How to start the counter when the page reach a certain position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter, setinterval

I am making a counter such that when the page scrolls to a certain position, the counter starts and animates to the number that is already set in the HTML.

I am a complete newbie in programming and was wondering how do I animate the counter. Also, how do I get the position of the page scroll.
Also in my code, I don't know if my logic is correct, but my `setInterval` isn't working at all. How do I proceed with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/a1t5m48f/2/

```
function Counter() {
  this.element = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-number');

  var intervalId;

  var that = this;

  this.init = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < that.element.length; i++) {
      intervalId = setInterval(that.animate(i), 1000);
    }

  }

  this.animate = function(i) {
    var j = 0;
    that.element[i].innerHTML = j;
    j++;
    if (j == parseInt(that.element[i].innerHTML)) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    console.log('hello');
  }

}

var counter = new Counter();
counter.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of one `setTimeout()` timer is more preferably than several `setInterval()` timers. In the `.init()` method counter target values stored in the inner properties, current values are set to zeros. Active counter indices stored in the `.indices` array. When target value will be reached in `.animate()`, the counter element index will be removed from this array. If there are some active counters in the array, we set a new timer to call next iteration after delay. Animation stops on empty `.indices` array.

```
var counter;
var pos = 200;

function Counter() {
  this.element = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-number');
  this.currentValues = [];
  this.targetValues = [];
  this.indices = [];
  var that = this;

  this.init = function() {
    var value;
    for (var i = 0; i < that.element.length; i++) {
      that.indices.push(i);
      that.targetValues.push(parseInt(that.element[i].innerHTML));
      that.currentValues.push(0);
      that.element[i].innerHTML = '0';
    }
    setTimeout(that.animate, 1000);
  }

  this.animate = function() {
    var value;
    var index;
    var indicesToRemove = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < that.indices.length; i++) {
      index = that.indices[i];
      if (that.currentValues[index] < that.targetValues[index]) {
        that.currentValues[index]++
        that.element[index].innerHTML = that.currentValues[index].toString();
      } else {
        indicesToRemove.push(i);
      }
    }

    while (indicesToRemove.length > 0) {
      i = indicesToRemove.pop();
      that.indices.splice(i, 1);
    }

    if (that.indices.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(that.animate, 1000);
    }
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  if ('undefined' === typeof counter
    && (document.body.scrollTop > pos || document.documentElement.scrollTop > pos)
  ) {
    counter = new Counter();
    counter.init();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function whatsMyPosition(){
    scrollPosition = {
        y: window.pageYOffset
    }
    scrollPosition.y === something ? do Something;
}
```